# Changing card value to 0 from Blank

Tags: powerbi

I have the following tables

```
Books with columns:

      BookCode

      BookType

      PublicationYear

Revnue with columns:

      BookCode

      BookRevenue
```

I have a Card View, that displays the sum of the column BookRevenue, with the following filters set:

On column BookType the filter is set to Fiction

On column PublicationYear filter is set to 2020

What I see now, is the word Blank when there is no BookRevnue for 2020. How do I get it to display 0 instead of Blank.

If I do a measure like this:

Fiction Sales 2020 = SUM ( BookRevenueTable[BookRevenue] ) + 0

This will get me all book revenue, so how can I apply the filters?

I am really new to DAX and was trying to the ISBLANK statement, but getting nowhere with it, in addition to having trouble with the filters. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your DAX statement that you are currently using which is giving you error?

Comment: See my edit to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isblank() evaluates if a result is blank and returns a true false. to use it in this case you can use the following:

Fiction Sales 2020 = IF(ISBLANK(SUM ( BookRevenueTable[BookRevenue] )),0,SUM ( BookRevenueTable[BookRevenue] ))

cheers